# How to scroll to bottom of div when new elements are added

Tags: javascript, scroll, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to make a chat application using Vue and Express.

At the moment, I want to make the container with the messages automatically scroll to the bottom when a new message is sent. I tried to do this by using a `scrollToEnd` function that selects the div container and assigns its `scrollHeight` to the `scrollTop`:

```
scrollToEnd: function () {
    var messages = this.$el.querySelector('#messages')
    messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight
}
```

This gives the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

For some reason, using the `querySelector` always returns null, also when I am testing it on other elements.

Below the full code for the component can be found.

```
<template>
    <div id="messages">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="msg in messages.slice().reverse()">{{ msg.message }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import MessageService from '@/services/MessageService'

export default {
    name: 'messages',
    data () {
        return {
            messages: []
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getMessages()

        this.$root.$on('newMessage', (msg) => {
            this.message = msg
            this.getMessages()
            this.scrollToEnd()
        })
    },
    methods: {
        async getMessages () {
            const response = await MessageService.fetchMessages()
            this.messages = response.data.messages
        },
        scrollToEnd: function () {
            var messages = this.$el.querySelector('#messages')
            messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [`this.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el)

> The root DOM element that the Vue instance is managing.

`this.$el` **is** the `#messages` div, there's no need to fetch it from the DOM.

Then, you could use `this.$el.lastElementChild.offsetTop` to get the last message and scroll to its top, so if it's long, you're not scrolling past its starting point.

*Here, I simplified the template a little to make it straight to the point.*

```
<template>
    <ul id="messages">
        <li v-for="msg in messages.slice().reverse()">{{ msg.message }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'messages',
    data() {
        return { messages: [] };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getMessages();
    },
    updated() {
        // whenever data changes and the component re-renders, this is called.
        this.$nextTick(() => this.scrollToEnd());
    },
    methods: {
        async getMessages () {
            // ...snip...
        },
        scrollToEnd: function () {
            // scroll to the start of the last message
            this.$el.scrollTop = this.$el.lastElementChild.offsetTop;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

If you really want to keep the `<div>` container, you could use a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

```
<template>
    <div id="messages">
        <ul ref="list">
            <li v-for="msg in messages.slice().reverse()">{{ msg.message }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then in the component, you can refer to it with `this.$refs.list`.

> `ref` is used to register a reference to an element or a child
> component. The reference will be registered under the parent
> component’s `$refs` object. If used on a plain DOM element, the
> reference will be that element; if used on a child component, the
> reference will be component instance.

While Vue examples often use the native DOM API to get around, using `ref` in this instance is way easier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it works now! Two tiny questions. Do I understand correctly that:

1. this.$el always references the top element within your template?

2. you should avoid using querySelector within Vue, as the ref attribute is cleaner and helps to avoid breaking your code, when something like markup names are changed?

Cheers

Comment: @joedoesnotknow You're right on both questions and I updated my answer to add information about that.

Comment: @EmileBergeron why is `$nextTick` required here?

Comment: @Nick I moved the `$nextTick` call to make it clearer that it's because of the updated data not being reflected yet in the DOM, so the `offsetTop` wouldn't have changed yet.